# Laravel5.1: validate time field (start time should be greater than end time)

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel.

I am trying to validate `$start_time` is greater than `$end_time`. They both are in a `H:i` format and are coming from database.

I had checked with the Laravel documentation and I got date_format:H:i for format.

Comment: Check `Before` and `After` of validation in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom validator to validate it, to do so you need to define the new custome validator under the `boot()` function in the `AppServiceProvider` class. Check the documentation for the full description [here](http://command-c://x-callback-url/safari?url=http%3A%2F%2Flaravel%2Ecom%2Fdocs%2Fmaster%2Fvalidation%23custom%2Dvalidation%2Drules):

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('date_is_greater', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($parameters[0],$value)->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($parameters[0],$parameters[1]));
    });
}
```

In this case the format is passed as the first parameter "H:i" or whatever valid DateTime format, and the $start_time is the second parameter.