# How to validate time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to validate time in Laravel. Ex:- I want that when user input the time between 8 PM to 10 PM then it will show the validation error. How can I achieve that in Laravel

Comment: You need to use `rule` in that. here is the example you can follow.
[https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-validation-for-time-formats]

Comment: You may also use @Umbert P. link. This also may helps you to validate time period. here is another link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685161/laravel5-1-validate-time-field-start-time-should-be-greater-than-end-time]

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use date_format rule validation

```
date_format:H:i
```

From docs

```
date_format:format
```

The field under validation must match the format defined according to the date_parse_from_format PHP function.

Answer (score 88):

Probably this code would work in your controller. However it won't validate times from different days (eg 9pm - 3am next day). `time_start` and `time_end` in this case should be provided as `HH:mm` but you can change it easily.

```
public function store(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'time_start' => 'date_format:H:i',
        'time_end' => 'date_format:H:i|after:time_start',
    ]);

    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Not working on Laravel 5.6. with the included seconds on one form. ```'time_start' => 'date_format:H:i:s',
        'time_end' => 'date_format:H:i|after:time_start',```

Comment: This works for me in Laravel 9

Answer (score 4):

Create DateRequest and then add

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Date;

use App\Http\Requests\FormRequest;


class DateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * @return bool
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * @return array
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [

            'start_date' => 'nullable|date|date_format:H:i A',
            'end_date' => 'nullable|date|after_or_equal:start_date|date_format:H:i A'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a comment, according to laravel docs "You should use either date or date_format when validating a field, not both"

Comment: Link to the quote in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-date-format

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
use Validator;
use Carbon\Carbon;


$timeHours = "7:00 PM";//change it to 8:00 PM,9:00 PM,10:00 PM  it works
$time = Carbon::parse($timeHours)->format('H');


$request['time'] = $time;
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'time' => ['required','integer','between:20,22']
]);


 if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd($validator->errors());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Lavavel 5.6:

Inside the file located in /app/Http/Requests/YourRequestValidation

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class YourRequestValidation extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'initial_time' => 'required',
            'end_time' => 'required',
            'end_time' => 'after:initial_time'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Custom message for validation
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {

        return [
            'initial_time.required' => 'Please, fill in the initial time',
            'end_time.required' => 'Please, fill in the end time.',
            'end_time.after' => 'The end time must be greater than initial time.'
        ];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should take a look to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) bit of the documentations. A custom rule sounds like your way to go.

Comment: That I know, but I want to know the logic how to validate this time

Comment: Take a look to this: http://carbon.nesbot.com/

You can then work with times easyly. for example:

$dt = Carbon::parse('2012-9-5 23:26:11.123789');
var_dump($dt->hour);