# Time validation rules in laravel 6 - after | before

Tags: laravel, validation, time, laravel-6, laravel-validation

checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467452/how-to-validate-time-in-laravel/39468429) kind of similar but not helpful in my case.

I have multiple time inputs where I need to assure that start time should not greater then end time.
[image]

My input Request dump is

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "nYb7gSp5TGTcrU9nNW9PMjJTduohLZFDLCzLGPbq"
  "timings" => array:8 [▼
    "day_1" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_2" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_3" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_4" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_5" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_6" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "day_7" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "1"
    ]
    "session" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "start" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "14:00 PM"
          1 => null
        ]
        "end" => array:2 [▼
          0 => "15:00 PM"
          1 => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

What I have did so far for this is

```
$rules = [
    'timings.session.*.start.*' => 'nullable|date_format:H:i|before:timings.session.*.end.*',
    'timings.session.*.end.*' => 'nullable|date_format:H:i|after:timings.session.*.start.*',
];

$messages = [
    'timings.session.*.start.*.before' => 'Start Time should be before End Time',
    'timings.session.*.end.*.after' => 'End Time should be after Start Time',
];
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

dd($validator->errors());
```

Still receiving false error message is

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#780 ▼
  #messages: array:2 [▼
    "timings.session.0.start.0" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "The timings.session.0.start.0 does not match the format H:i."
      1 => "Start Time should be before End Time"
    ]
    "timings.session.0.end.0" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "The timings.session.0.end.0 does not match the format H:i."
      1 => "End Time should be after Start Time"
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Questions:

a.) **How to put correct validation rules for time input which insure start time should not greater then end time?**

b.) **How to put another validation rule for match at least one checkbox is ticked for day select?**

Thanks, Hope it will help other people too.

Comment: tried with "H:i A" also

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, After some hit and try I found a solution myself just need to remove date_format

**Updated Rule is**

```
$rules = [
    'timings.session.*.start.*' => 'nullable|before:timings.session.*.end.*',
    'timings.session.*.end.*' => 'nullable|after:timings.session.*.start.*',
];
```

But still awating for second rule, at least any one checkbox is ticked

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use like this may help you

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'timings.session.*.start.*'  => 'required|date_format:h:iA',
    'timings.session.*.end.*'=>'required|date_format:h:iA|after:start_time',
]);
```