# Laravel date_format validation not working

Tags: laravel, validation, time, laravel-validation

here is my code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'clock_time_from' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
      'clock_time_to'   => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:clock_time_from',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'clock_time_from.required' => 'Time from required',
        'clock_time_from.date_format' => 'Time From- Please write time correctly',

        'clock_time_to.required'   => 'Time to required',
        'clock_time_to.date_format' => 'Time To- Please write time correctly',
    ];
}
```

when i put this time in input field like:
from: 9:00
to: 13:00

its not working and return me the validation message:
'Time From- Please write time correctly',

so what did i wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467452/how-to-validate-time-in-laravel

Comment: @KhayamKhan I read this and i write correctly but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H` format is with leading zeros, try with `09:00`

Comment: How to write validation if written without leading zero?

Comment: [G](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)