# Time validation between two time inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

Is it possible to validate and compare between 2 time inputs using the available rules, or I will have to have custom rule in this case?

I have 2 time inputs - start and end. They are in the format `HH:mm` and I need the end date to be greater than the start date.

Is there a combination I can have with the available rules to do that, or I should just create a custom rule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate time in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467452/how-to-validate-time-in-laravel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467452/how-to-validate-time-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate with laravel validators:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'time_start' => 'date_format:H:i',
    'time_end' => 'date_format:H:i|after:time_start',
]);
```

**Note:** date_format only validates times in 24 hours format at maximum. If you have to validate more than 24 hours you have yo use a custom regex validation.

Links to Laravel documentation:

- [date_format](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-date-format)
- [after](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-after)

Comment: Do you have any idea why it says my time is not matching the format? I tried both `HH:MM` and `HH:mm`, when I dd the `$request->start_time` for example, the string is `"11:22"` yet it does not match

Comment: The correct format is `H:i`

Comment: @VincentDecaux thanks, it works! Do you know why though? Because Laravel docs link to Date Format, which in turn have link for the Time Formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php. There I saw `HH:mm`

Comment: @Stackerito Laravel valides dateTime and not times, you should use the Php date formats, not time formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php